# Unknown field(s) (password1, password2) specified for User

Tags: python, django, forms, view

I am new to django and trying to make login and log out and register form for user consisting of username, email, password1, and password2 (for confirm password).

when i remove passward1 and passward2 two fields from fields in meta class , I can get a form but without email field

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'passward1', 'passward2']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


# Create your views here.

def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm
    return render(request, 'register.html', {"form": form} )
```

Comment: passward ? You meant password ?

Comment: Sorry! yes password